# Efficiently comparing total values of two unsorted arrays

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, sorting, efficiency

The general form of my question would be, what is the most efficient way to compare the total values of two different arrays to see which one is greater?

Would be as simple as prefix sum ($O(n)$) for both arrays? Or is there a more efficient method?

The specific question I'm staring at is:

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two unsorted arrays that each contains $n$ positive integers. Assume that all $2n$ integers are distinct. We say that $A$ is **totally greater than** $B$ if it is possible to re-order both arrays in a way that $A[i] \gt B[i]$ for every index $1 \le i \le n$. Describe an efficient algoirthm that for given arrays $A$ and $B$ determines if $A$ is totally greater than $B$.

If Prefix sum (adding $A[0]+A[1]$, then adding that sum to $A[3]$) is $O(n)$ and you have to run it twice for $O(2n)$, I don't see how you could improve on that efficiency.

All comparison sorts are $O(n(log(n))$ and Bucket Sort is $O(n)$...but this prompt would suggest there's some other efficient way to sort and compare two arrays.

Comment: Prefix sum doesn't work. You have to sort the arrays first. Try to come up with a concrete algorithm and then prove that it works.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Prefix sum would work if you don't care about sorting, as the prompt suggests. If I add together 4,1,3,2 to get 12 it doesn't matter what order the integers are. Otherwise I can't see anything more efficient than Quicksort / Mergesort (n log n) and an O(n) comparison traversal.

Comment: I repeat my suggestion. Come up with a concrete algorithm and prove that it works.

Comment: I repeat my response: "I can't see anything more efficient than Quicksort / Mergesort (n log n) and an O(n) comparison traversal." That's my second suggested algorithm, beyond comparing prefix sums. My question is, is there something more efficient?

Comment: You are asking several questions in your actual post. Can you clarify what question you are actually after? Is it the following: "Is there an $o(n\log n)$ algorithm for this problem?"

Comment: My question is the first line: "what is the most efficient way to compare the total values of two different arrays [of integers] to see which one is [totally] greater?" The specific prompt underneath it is not as important as determining what the most efficient method for comparing two arrays' total values is.

Comment: I don't know what "total value" is. Are you looking for the most efficient solution to the highlighted text (the "specific question") or for anything else?

Comment: Total value is the summation of values contained at each index at each array. The highlighted text is ultimately what I'm after but I'm seeking the more general case just to understand -- in theory it's the same answer to both questions.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "compare the total values of two different arrays". In any case, any such task would take $\Omega(n)$ since it potentially depends on all elements in the array, and going over all of them necessarily takes $\Omega(m)$.

Comment: OrdinaryHuman, your question is hard to follow and confusing.  I encourage you to edit the question to clarify what you are asking, and to address all the feedback you've gotten.  Part of your question talks about the total value of the array, but then the part you quoted is something else entirely.  The "total value" of an array A would normally be understood as the sum of the values in the array A (i.e., $A[1]+\dots +A[n]$), which is very different from what the "specific question" you quoted is talking about.  So as it stands the question seems unclear to me -- any community votes?

Comment: Second, Yuval is absolutely right.  You asked "would prefix sum work?"  The way to figure that out is to try to write down precisely what algorithm you have in mind (state more precisely exactly how you plan to use prefix sum techniques, using pseudocode) and then see if you can prove it correct, or if you can find a counterexample where it fails.  Don't just guess -- work through the details.  If you go through that exercise, you should be able to work out for yourself whether your idea works -- and then you should be in a good position to edit your question to show your work.

Comment: @D.W. The point is to provide a general case for the broader community (comparison of two arrays) and then as a backdrop, the origin of the inquiry as applied to a specific prompt. The "total value" of an array is what I'm specifically referring to, I'm finding your comment confusing because it's not clear to me where the discrepancy exists.

Comment: Second, laying out the steps of the prefix sum algorithm seems trivial, anyone should have a simple time understanding the steps involved in summing an array's values efficiently or have no issues locating that information, so I'm not sure where the value lies in explaining the trivial steps as opposed to say, discussing the virtues of different algorithms or approaches.

Comment: @OrdinaryHuman, at this point I have no idea what you are asking.  "A general case" - None of that is stated in the question.  If that's what you want, edit the question to state that.  However, the difference between "sum of all values" vs "what's in the quotation" is so enormous that any question that tried to encompass both would almost certainly be too broad for this site.  The answer to your question is going to depend on what you're trying to do, so rather than asking a general/broad question, you should just ask about whatever specific task you are trying to achieve.

Comment: At this point, we've given you lots of feedback, and suggested you edit the question to clarify, but I haven't seen any edits yet.  I'm going to put this on hold to give you a chance to think about how to pose the question in a less confusing way and edit the question accordingly.  If you can edit it into a form where it's clear what you are asking, it can be re-opened at that time.

Comment: We should probably remove it then -- @D.W. I'm unable to decipher your response since the question provides, to me, is clear: what's the most efficient way to compare the summation of values in an array? But thanks for your feedback, this has been really insightful.

Comment: OK, let me try explaining another way. The question you quoted (the "specification question you're staring at") has nothing to do with the summation of values in an array -- it is about something else entirely -- so it is super-confusing to have it there.  That makes it very hard to tell just what you are asking.